# When can we factor out the time dimension?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, dg.differential-geometry

First of all, my knowledge of both GR and differential geometry is quite weak, so forgive me if the physics here doesn't make much sense.

Let $(M, g)$ be a smooth, connected Lorentzian manifold of dimension $n$.  Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to M$ be a smooth curve such that the pullback of $g$ through $f$ is everywhere negative (where we've chosen an orientation on $\mathbb{R}$); we say that $f$ is time-like.  Say that we can "factor" $f$ out of $M$ if there exists a manifold $S$ of dimension $n-1$ and an isomorphism $M\simeq S\times \mathbb{R}$ so that the map $\mathbb{R}\to M\simeq S\times \mathbb{R}\to S$ is constant and the map $\mathbb{R}\to M\simeq S\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the identity.  Intuitively, this factorization exhibits $f$ as "time" in some reference frame, and $S$ as space.  My question is:

> For which $(M, g)$ can every time-like path be factored out?

Minkowski space seems like an obvious example unless I'm missing something; it seems one can take a tangent vector to $f$ at any point and consider a perpendicular subspace to that vector as $S$.  I'd accept as an answer a characterization of all such $(M, g)$ in dimension $4$, or some nice sufficient condition on $M$ for factorization to always work.

If the motivation isn't obvious already, this is supposed to codify the intuition that in my reference frame, I seem to be standing still -- and that the same is true for everyone else, even if they seem to me to be moving.  My apologies if I've overloaded terms, or used them incorrectly.

---

Added:  Note that this condition is much stronger than stable causality; indeed, it certainly implies stable causality, as choosing any timelike path $f$ and then considering the given projection to $\mathbb{R}$ gives a global time function.  However, I am asking for (1) a product structure on $M$ for each path $f$ and (2) in order to formalize the notion that I seem to be standing still (to myself), the projection of $f$ to $S$ must be constant.

---

Added:  I don't think global hyperbolicity suffices either.  The theorem of Geroch (it and other splitting theorems are discussed [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1933), for example) does indeed give a decomposition of $M$ as $\mathbb{R}\times S$.  But I don't think this is enough.  In particular, I am asking for the following---for **every** timelike path $f: \mathbb{R}\to M$, there is a product structure $M\simeq \mathbb{R}\times S$ such that the projection to $\mathbb{R}$ is a section of $f$, and that $f$ is constant upon projection to $S$.  This is much stronger than Geroch's splitting theorem, as far as I can tell.

---

Added:  As the accepted answerer rightly points out in the comments to his question, I was wrong to claim that my condition is stronger than global hyperbolicity.  They are in fact equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds to me like you're asking that your spacetime admit a family of [Cauchy surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) (modulo annoyances like having $f$ be closed and acausal).   There's a theorem of Geroch which guarantees that this is equivalent to [global hyperbolicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic).

I don't think that globally hyperbolic and stably causal are equivalent conditions, but I'm not an expert on causality conditions in GR, so take this claim with a grain of salt.

Comment: Reading the wikipedia article, it seems to me that this implies that *one path* can be factored out in the sense I described; does this guarantee it for every path?

Comment: You're worried that $S$ may depend on $f$?  It might in the metric category, but in the topological category, any two $S$ are certainly isomorphic.

Comment: I'm worried that the projection of $f$ to $S$ might not be constant.  If you read the question carefully, you'll see we need a *different* product structure for each $f$.

Comment: I still suspect the two conditions are essentially equivalent, as long as you're not worried about metric structure.  

We know that $M$ is globally hyperbolic, so let's equate $M = S \times \mathbb{R}$. Let $f_0$ be the "base" path, given by $t \mapsto (f_0(t),t)$. Now suppose we have some other path $f_1$, given by $t \mapsto (f_1(t),t)$. I claim that, as long as $S$ is path-connected, for each $t$, we can find a diffeomorphism $d_t: S \to S$ which moves $f_1(t)$ to $f_0(t)$.  Moreover, we can make these diffs depend smoothly on $t$. That should
give product structure you want...


Comment: Should this claim be obvious?  It certainly suffices.  (This is where my lack of diff. geom. knowledge is apparent.)

Comment: Take a path connecting the first point to the second point.  Thicken the path to a neighborhood.  Said neighborhood is diffeomorphic to the ball.  It should at least be intuitive that you can always map the ball onto itself in a way that moves any given point to the origin.  Just grab the point and drag it where you want it.

Comment: Indeed, and this can certainly be done smoothly in t.  +1, accepted.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

The answer below is not correct.  Upon further reflection, I believe that the correct causality condition is indeed **global hyperbolicity** and not the weaker stable causality.

---

I believe this is a causality condition known as **stably causal**.  You can read about this in Wald's "General Relativity" Chapter 8, in particular his Theorem 8.2.2.

A spacetime $(M,g)$ is **stably causal** if there exists a continuous nowhere vanishing timelike vector $t$ such that the spacetime $(M,\tilde g)$ with
$$\tilde g = g - t^\flat \otimes t^\flat,$$
where $t^\flat$ is the dual one-form to $t$ relative to $g$, has no closed timelike curves.

Wald's Theorem 8.2.2 says that this is equivalent to the existence of a global time function on $M$.

*Theorem 8.2.2*  A spacetime $(M,g)$ is stably causal if and only if there is a differentiable function $f$ on $M$ such that its gradient is a past directed timelike vector field.

There is a whole hierarchy of causality conditions in GR.  *Global hyperbolicity* implies stable causality and this in turn implies *strong causality*.  <del>Global hyperbolicity might be too strong.</del>

Comment: According to Wikipedia "stably causal" is something different, or at least not obviously the same.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_conditions#Stably_causal)  The book doesn't seem to be on google books; can you elaborate?